to make data layer variable and Custom java script variable work the same in GTM
You need to write code for a javascript variable in GTM that will work similarly to a data layer variable. My current code doesn't work in GSM, what's wrong with it?
function() {    
  var res = null

  if (dataLayer[dataLayer.length - 1] == undefined) {
    res = 'undefined'
  } else {
      res = dataLayer[dataLayer.length - 1]['eventCategory']
  }
  return res
}

Task: to make data layer variable and Custom java script variable work the same in GTM



Just curious why you need to rewrite JS to perform like Datalayer Variable. Did you run into some problem?

The second image is just a copy of your first code excerpt, so can be removed. The first image could be replaced with a couple of lines of text. Could you describe the symptoms that you observe in the words doesn't work in GSM

There are two ways to get the latest value from certain key in datalayer
1.
var latestValue = null;
for (var i = window.dataLayer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (window.dataLayer[i]['your_key'] !== undefined) {
        latestValue = window.dataLayer[i]['your_key'];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(latestValue);




var variableValue = google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].dataLayer.get('your_key');
console.log(variableValue);


Replace your_key to the key you need and have a try.
On 2rd part please remember to replace GTM-XXXXXX to your GTM Container ID.
But these 2 methods should quite the same as you get via DataLayer variable.
You can share more problem about why we need to get the value from JS.
